# WP Multisite Sub-Domain Error

Tags: multisite

Just created a new multisite subdomain install for a new website with my Google Cloud compute engine setup, running on vestaCP using the Ubuntu 16.04 OS...the installation went fine for the main website:

but when I create a new site/subdomain it doesn't work: when I click dashboard on the new site install I get this error:

"You must log in to access the admin area" then, when I visit the new site it redirects me to a different website on my server:

can someone please help. I have tried doing all that I know, it hasn't work: Settingup DNS, Setting the A and CNAME Record and all... I honestly need some guidance here: Thanks.

Comment: Have you waited 24-48 hours for the domain and the subdomains to propagate?

Comment: can you be specific about where you're redirected and what's generating the error message you mentioned? Keep in mind you need to set the DNS records before you create the site, and you'll need to refer to google cloud compute/vestaCP docs for the ideal way to do that

Comment: Also, when you say click dashboard, does this mean you can access the frontend of those new subdomain sites? It isn't clear from your question, lots of ambiguity

Comment: I Have waited for over 24 hours-48hours nothing changed.....

Comment: I Have waited for over 24 hours-48hours nothing changed..... And about setting the DNS first before creating the site, that wasn't something i did, wud try it ur way... i cant access the both the frontend and backend of the new site...whenever i try to visit the backend like: https://ng.trackapro.com/wp-admin/ i usually will get this message: "You must log in to access the admin area." then whenever i visit the site: https://ng.trackapro.com: i get redirect to another different domain on my server sharing thesame dedicated ip....not sure why this is happening.

Comment: You need to point those subdomains to the same wp installation folder. You said they load another website, also it's no DNS propagation issue since you're served with a custom error message from some website or wp itself.